# printQueue objects not replicating to Global Catalog

Tags: global-catalog, replication, active-directory

I have a forest that printQueue objects have either disappeared from GC's or never were there. So now I am getting 1388 errors that the GC has to pull a full replica. Anyone else seen this? The source domain has never had an AD restore nor USN rollback nor DC offline for more than tombstone lifetime. Google and Bing not helping.

EDIT: Submitting MS ticket.

Comment: I did not Google or Bing hard enough I guess; the REPADMIN command has the "rehost" subcommand which turfs the other domain's entries from the GC, then triggers a full replication back.

Does not really explain why this happened, however.